# When does TalkBack start when an Activity is opened?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, talkback, accessibility

I would like to perform some accessibility actions on my screen as soon as it opens. The problem is that I don't know when `TalkBack` has finished starting.

If I send my `AccessibilityEvent` on a regular lifecycle method, like `onStart` or `onResume`, the `TalkBack` will be still starting, so it doesn't work. I also tried sending the event on `onPostResume` ([even if I am not intended to use this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPostResume())), but even then `TalkBack` has not been started yet.

The current solution is to use a delayed call of 100ms on my `onResume` method to send the accessibility event. I think it is not reliable because on some phones the `TalkBack` may be starting yet while in other phones it may be started for a long time already.

Disclaimer: I know that I am not intended to modify the accessibility behavior, as accessibility users are expecting a consistent behavior. However, I am trying to improve my application accessibility based on research and `TalkBack` users feedback.